# String replacement excercise

Tags: vb.net

How to replace this string so that after the replacement work the string will be free of any spaces?

This is the string:

```
dim InitialString as string = "Hello world !!!"
```

Comment: U mean just space? `"dim InitialString as string = \"Hello world !!!\"".Replace(" ", "")`

Comment: I thought he was talking about space, as in memory space

Comment: @Cybernate: Your code not working. VS says 'Expression Expected'

Comment: @Yoga: in a good question you would also provide the desired result string. Saves  so much guessing.

Comment: @Henk Holterman: Maybe stackoverflow.com is not the right place for me. Kinda broad daylight bully by existing old members. I will find other places to ask my questions :(

Comment: @Yoga: You're being downvoted and closed because you're not making appropriate research before asking questions, or else your questions show no effort on your part. You should read the FAQ.

Comment: @Yoga, did you get around to reading the FAQ ? And why is advice for a better question bullying?

Comment: @Henk just send him teh codez already!

Answer (score 3):

```
Dim myString As String = "Hello world !!!"

myString = myString.Replace(" ","")
```

Comment: You can also use `myString = myString.Replace(" ", String.Empty)`.

Answer (score 1):

To use string replacement, you can do it like this :

```
dim InitialString as string = "Hello world !!!"
' We can use the Replace method like this
InitialString  = InitialString.Replace("world", "planet")
' InitialString now says "Hello planet !!!"

' We can remove the ' ' SPACE character by replacing it with an empty string
InitialString  = InitialString.Replace(" ", "")

' We release the resources that InitialString uses like this :
InitialString = NOTHING
```

Comment: Please don't tell newcomers to VB.NET to set things to `Nothing`, it's so often misused and unnecessary...

Comment: @minitech You're completely right, but I wasn't sure if the OP was asking how to free() a string or if they were asking how to remove spaces